# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ELYSSU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ado9ytn\cryptography\

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to install `scrapy` in my Windows system, but It is showing me the below error:-

```
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ELYSSU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ado9ytn\cryptography\
```

Answer (score 14):

Enter the following command and install again to install without any problems.

```
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed pip setuptools
```

Comment: I had to specify pip version: `pip3 install --upgrade --ignore-installed pip setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

That means your pip3 needs to be updated. You can process the upgrade command and upgrade the setuptools then it could work.